# MSBuild from Powershell

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I'm trying to run a Sync from MSBuild (From Powershell) that also includes Pre Sync Commands.

I am unable to get the commands right. I've tried multiple ways, but the final way I'm up to is :

```
[string[]]$msdeployArgs = @(
  "-verb:sync",
  "-preSync:runCommand='$preSyncCommand',waitInterval=30000",
  "-source:dirPath=$sourceFolder",
  "-dest:computerName=$serverName,userName=$username,password=$password,authType=basic,dirPath=$serviceFolder", 
  "-postSync:runCommand=$postSyncCommand,waitInterval=30000"
)

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" $msdeployArgs
```

I get the following error.

> Error: Unrecognized argument
>   '"-preSync:runCommand='F:\Projects\Unleashed\Release_Scripts\WindowsServices\deployTopShelfServicePreCommands.cmd
>   Unleashed.Maintenance.JobScheduler
>   C:\MyCompany\Services\MyCompany.Maintenance.JobScheduler',waitInterval=30000"'.
>   All arguments must begin with "-".

Note that after the PreSyncCommand, is params that I want to pass to the CMD file (For it to know where to uninstall the existing service from etc.

I've ran that params via EchoArgs.exe, and the args are fine.

If it matters (It might), I'm running the powershell script from TeamCity.

Comment: May be a quoting problem? You could try with `""$preSyncCommand""`

Comment: Found the issue. I'll add it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue. As it turns out, it isn't powershell with the issue, but MSDeploy. MSDeploy as far as I can see does not allow you to pass batch files with parameters. Removing the parameters works fine (But then you need to hardcode them in your batch file, or work out some other way of generating the bat files on the fly).